# How to get a count of Repetition of specific Table of Strings which are used in another table ? (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table name "CompanyID"

```
ID  | Name
_____________
AAA | Semsung

BBB | NoKeea

CCC | JOKER

DDD | Papa
```

now I have another table "DETAILS"

```
Product | Company | Date
_________________________
asdfasdf| AAA     | asdfd

asdfasdf| AAA     | asdfd

asdfasdf| BBB     | asdff

asdfasdf| BBB     | asdff

asdfasdf| BBB     | asdff

asdfasdf| BBB     | asdff

asdfasdf| CCC     | asdfd

asdfasdf| CCC     | asdfd

asdfasdf| CCC     | asdfd
```

Now I want to get a count of how many AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD are there

```
ID | TotalCount
_______________
AAA| 2

BBB| 4

CCC| 3

DDD| 0
```

I tried using conditions like CompanyID.ID = Details.Company
but with that, I also get results like

```
AAA 2

AAA 0

AAA 0

AAA 0

BBB 4
```

Please Help Me

Comment: Please, provide the body of query you use...

Comment: You would appear to have values that look like duplicates in the first table but are subtly different.

Answer (score 1):

You need a LEFT join of the tables and aggregation:

```
SELECT c.ID, COUNT(d.Company) AS TotalCount
FROM CompanyID AS c LEFT JOIN Details AS d
ON d.Company = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Where as @Forpas answer is enough, you can also try-

```
SELECT CompanyID.ID, DCount("[Company]","[DETAILS]","[Company]='" & CompanyID.ID & "'") AS [Total Count] FROM CompanyID;
```